# Directory for saving/accessing files in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, leanback

I'm currently developing an app in *Android Studio* for Android TV on a mac. Ultimately I want to load local image files as card images in a *VerticalGridFragment* where a card id and an image filename have matching numbers. For the sake of prototyping, right now I'm just trying to set up best practices (as a complete novice) with a single **1.jpg** file that will appear on every card.

I'm using the included Android TV emulator and assume I shouldn't attempt to use access or make use of any OSX file system. So my two questions are:

1. While I'm prototyping and trying to get 1.jpg to be the image for
   each card, where should I place this file in a manner that I can
   access using a file path string for internal storage, such as */root/1.jpg*
   which I can later change to */root/$.jpg* where *$* is a dynamic id
   associated with each card. This needs to satisfy both the emulator
   being able to access the file, a device being able to access the file when the app is finished, and me being able to place files there
   from my host os while prototyping.
2. A follow-on question. When the app is finished I obviously won't be
   relying on manually placing image files. Will the solution to the
   above also provide a straightforward means of saving images to this
   directory on a device?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I've got my head around this now:

Inside Android Studio, there's a Monitor utility in which there's a File Explorer. Using this, you can browse, and save to the directory structure that the emulator's using.

Most importantly, there *is* a standard assigned directory for apps to save and open from on internal storage. It can be found in the file browser at `/data/data/com.applicationname/files/`

From any app, it can be referenced for saving to or opening from using `getFilesDir()`, which answers question 2.